# How to approach regular languages using the pumping lemma?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, regular-language

I have struggles understanding how generally approach and test regular languages using the pumping lemma. Givent the following language:

$L = \{ \text{s} \mid  \text{s} \in \{ c, d \}^* \land  |s|_c = |s|_d \}$

I would like to test whether it contains the words $cccdd$ and $cdcdcd$  and whether I'm dealing with a regular language at all.

What I have tried sofar is to use the definition of pumping lemma:

Condition 1. $|v|≥1$

Condition 2. $|uv|≤n$

Condition 3. $∀_i∈N_0 :uv^iw∈L$

So I have tried first check whether the language is regular but struggle to come up with a proof:

I assume that a word contains $|s|_c = |s|_d$ an equal amount of $c$ and $d$. Thus $|c^n * d^n| = 2n$. 
If I reformulate $cd$ into $uvw$, then $uv$ has to consists only of $c$.
Based on condition Condition 1. $|v|≥1$ there are more $c$ then $d$ which contradicts the language definition.

Appreciate any insights regarding how to formulate a correct proof and test it.

Comment: This [reference answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular) to pumping lemma questions on the computer science stack exchange may be useful.

Comment: "What I have tried sofar is to use the definition of regular languages:" You are using the pumping lemma, which is not a definition of regular languages.

Comment: Updated the question, sry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the pumping lemma, you assume your language $L$ is regular. That means there exist $N$ such that every word $w$ in $L$ can be written $w = xyz$ with $|xy|<N$ and $\forall k\in \mathbb N, xy^kn \in L$.

Then, you have to find a word (depending on $N$), that can't check that condition and prove it, and then you have a proof by contradiction.

$c^Nd^N$ is a good one in that case, as in any working decomposition $xyz$, $y$ cannot contain any $d$ since $|xy|<n$. Therefore :

- $|xy^2z|_c = |xyz|_c + |y|_c >|w|_c$
- $|xy^2z|_d = |xyz|_d = |w|_c$

This is a contradiction since $xy^2z\in L$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So its save to say that cccddcccdd dos not belong to the language  and cdcdcd belongs to it. However, the language as such cant be regular by the decomposition example?

Comment: Yes, cccddcccdd is not in the language, and cdcdcd is, but that doesn't give you any information about the regularity of the language ! You should maybe try to go back to the definition of a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), that might help you.